# Make program go through all slides too

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I already have a code that makes it so I can enter a shape's name and change the text that it has to what I enter, but I wanted to make it go through all slides too, but it seems like I made something wrong and I don't know what it is.

The code is supposed to let you enter the max amount of slides, then count until it's done while checking the slides for the text with the name that you enter, but when I enter the last InputBox it just crashes, can anyone tell me where is the problem?

The code is this one:

```
Public Sub TextoEspecifico()
Dim Name$
Maxnum = InputBox("Enter max number of slides")
TextReemp = InputBox("Enter replacement word")
FindWord = InputBox("Enter name of text box")
j = 1
While j <= Maxnum
    For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides(j).Shapes.Count
        Name = ActivePresentation.Slides(j).Shapes(i).Name
        If Name = FindWord Then
            ActivePresentation.Slides(j).Shapes(i).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = TextReemp
        End If
    Next i
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Where did you define `Maxnum` and other variables? (Hint: it is best to always explicitly declare your variables). BTW, `j` is never incremented in your code, so you will stay on the first slide.

Comment: Thank you so much! Seems like it was either the loop or not declaring but now it works properly